# GitBlit groovy hook script PullCommand not working

Tags: git, groovy, jgit, gitblit

I am looking for ANY help with this. I have gitblit set up, I have used a slightly modified version of one of the groovy hooks scripts. I need a hook script that deploys the head to a folder, which can then be used as a webroot for that site in WAMP. Basically, the changes will be pushed to gitblit, and the script will deploy those changes on our development server, without any manual intervention. I had this working on subversion, with a simple svn update on a working copy as the webroot. Gitblit doesn't seem to be that easy.

If the clone folder already exists, I want it to perform a Pull command on the master. The clone code all works correctly and successfully creates a clone of the repos. But then when I push more changes, and the clone exists, it throws this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.eclipse.j
git.api.Git.pull() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

The full groovy script is below. I'm a bit of a noob to groovy, and haven't used java properly for years, so any help would give you god-like status. Thanks in advance.

```
import com.gitblit.GitBlit
import com.gitblit.Keys
import com.gitblit.models.RepositoryModel
import com.gitblit.models.TeamModel
import com.gitblit.models.UserModel
import com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils
import com.gitblit.utils.StringUtils
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.*;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.*;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils
import org.slf4j.Logger

// Indicate we have started the script
logger.info("Deploying website (In Repository ${repository.name}) for ${user.username}")

def rootFolder = 'C:/Program Files/wamp/www/git-repositories'
def bare = false
def cloneAllBranches = true
def cloneBranch = 'refs/heads/master'
def includeSubmodules = true

def repoName = repository.name
def destinationFolder = new File(rootFolder, StringUtils.stripDotGit(repoName))
def srcUrl = 'file://' + new File(gitblit.getRepositoriesFolder(), repoName).absolutePath

// if there is already a clone
if (destinationFolder.exists()) {
    PullCommand cmd = Git.pull();
}
else
{
    // clone the repository
    logger.info("cloning ${srcUrl} to ${destinationFolder}")
    CloneCommand cmd = Git.cloneRepository();
    cmd.setBare(bare)
    if (cloneAllBranches)
        cmd.setCloneAllBranches(true)
    else
        cmd.setBranch(cloneBranch)
    cmd.setCloneSubmodules(includeSubmodules)
    cmd.setURI(srcUrl)
    cmd.setDirectory(destinationFolder)
    Git git = cmd.call();
    git.repository.close()

    // report clone operation success back to pushing Git client
    clientLogger.info("${repoName} cloned to ${destinationFolder}")
}
```

UPDATE: There are no more errors, but none of the changes seem to be pulling into the cloned repos:

```
logger.info("Development clone already exists, pulling changes...")

def cloneLocation = rootFolder + "/" + StringUtils.stripDotGit(repoName) + "";

FileRepository repo = new FileRepository("C:/Program Files/wamp/www/git-repositories/brightercreative.dev");

Git git = new Git(repo); 

logger.info("Pulling changes from "+cloneLocation )

git.pull();  

git.repository.close();

logger.info("Pulled changes "+cloneLocation )
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Woops, I added the wrong code, at the moment, it simply deletes the clone, and then re-clones it. This is fine, but with big projects like ours, this takes far too long. I removed the "FileUtils.delete(destinationFolder, FileUtils.RECURSIVE)" and added the PullCommand cmd = Git.pull(); line.

Comment: The PullCommand cmd = Git.pull(); is the line that is failing.

Comment: There's no `static` `pull` method in `Git`, it's an [instance method](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-3.2.0.201312181205-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html#pull()), so you need a `Git` instance pointing to the repository.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense, so I need to create a new Git object, and then execute the pull method on that object?

Comment: Should do...  Maybe `new Git( new FileRepository( destinationFolder ) ).pull()`?  Not tried any of this, so that's a guess ;-)

Comment: Thats pretty much exactly the code im using, but first I got an error saying that It couldn't resolve the class "FileRepository". I assume I need to import that class - "import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.FileRepository;" that doesn't work. I also found this: "import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepository;" that one throws an error too.

Comment: I'm guessing it's `org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository`.  That says it should point to the `.git` folder I think...  What error are you getting?

Comment: Looks like the import was missing the 'internal' bit. Okay, so there are no errors now, seems to be running, but the cloned repos isn't being updated with the changes. I can probably figure out the rest, thanks for the help!

Comment: Right, this is working, but there is a small issue - mainly down to my knowledge of  git. I have a clone of the remote at C:/repositories/www.mytestwebsite.dev. That folder has my source files from the repository, and then a .git folder. When I am pulling, which one do I set as the destinationFolder  for creating the repository in code? The code runs, but nothing seems to happen, none of my changes are being pulled.

Comment: By the way, If i do "cd C:/repositories/www.mytestwebsite.dev" then "git pull", it sucessfully pulls all of the updates. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of my depth on this one now...  Maybe delete this and ask a new question about this issue instead?  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to @tim_yates for his help on this. Finally figured this out.

```
def cloneLocation = rootFolder + "/" + StringUtils.stripDotGit(repoName) + "";

// create the file repository object
FileRepository repo = new FileRepository("C:/myclonedrepos/.git");

// use the repository object to create a git object
Git git = new Git(repo); 

// create a pull command
PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull();  

// call the pull command
pullCmd.call();

git.repository.close();

logger.info("Pulled changes "+cloneLocation )

// report clone operation success back to pushing Git client
clientLogger.info("${repoName} pulled to ${destinationFolder}")
```

Comment: Hey @brighterdean, using fetch and reset origin/master keeps your repos cloned, using merge would keep local changes (but maybe you want that?)

Comment: @brighterdean
I have two Private Gitblit server A and B, I need to keep B in sync with A, I have found It is possbile using Groovy Posh hook, But I don't know where to configure this Hook and how ?, Any help would be appreciated, Thanks